# Prevent Bootstrap scrollspy from adding URL hash

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I've implemented Bootstrap 3.0's scrollspy as follows:

```
<nav id="navProposalPreview">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#previewTitlePage">Title Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#previewDisplay">Display</a></li>
        <li><a href="#previewAddlServices">Additional Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div>
        <p id="previewTitlePage"></p>
        <div>Stuff</div>
        <p id="previewDisplay"></p>
        <div>Other stuff</div>
        <p id="previewAddlServices"></p>
        <div>Last stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm initializing it like this:

```
$('.modal-body').scrollspy({ target: '#navProposalPreview', offset: 20 });
```

It sets the active `li` as expected as you scroll and also allows for navigating to sections using the links.  The problem is that when you click on the links it will append the link to the URL in a hash eg. mysite.com/#previewDisplay.  I don't want the URL to be changed at all.

I've run into this before in tabs I believe and I forget if the solution was to set the `data-parent` or add a click event like this:

```
$previewModal.find('#navProposalPreview a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Adding `data-parent` isn't relative to scrollspy like it is for tabs and the click event above results in the link not navigating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean `data-target` did you try that `adding data-targer="#`

Comment: @nol: To what elements?

Answer (score 5):

ok here it goes via [bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/s3WuS/)

```
**"To keep URLs intact, use the data-target attribute instead of href="#"."**
```

like this

```
data-target="#"
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

here is a working [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s3WuS/) sorry for the confusion! `data-target="#navbar"` for on the container of where the anchor links to

Comment: Are you saying eg. my 2nd `li` should be `<li><a data-target="#previewDisplay">Display</a></li>`?

Comment: That doesn't work plus the setting of the target is what I'm doing in my javascript (see original post).